# C#: Preferred pattern for functions requiring arguments that implement two interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, generics

The argument to my function `f()` must implement two different interfaces that are not related to each other by inheritance, `IFoo` and `IBar`. I know of two different ways of doing this. The first is to declare an empty interface that inherits from both:

```
public interface IFooBar : IFoo, IBar
{
    // nothing to see here
}

public int f(IFooBar arg)
{
    // etc.
}
```

This, of course, requires that the classes declare themselves as implementing `IFooBar` rather than `IFoo` and `IBar` separately.

The second way is to make `f()` generic with a constraint:

```
public int f<T>(T arg) where T : IFoo, IBar
{
    // etc.
}
```

Which of these do you prefer, and why? Are there any non-obvious advantages or disadvantages to each?

Comment: Second is quite shorter and more expressive.

Comment: I would suggest the generic method. It frees the implementing object from having to know that two of its interfaces are used together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second option is more flexible.  By introducing a new interface, you're forcing classes to implement a third interface, which will only be possible if they have a reference to your library (where the interface is defined).

By using generic constraints, the class only needs a reference to the library containing `IFoo` and `IBar`, and not `IFooBar`.

Comment: Also, create an interface, release it in the wild, never touch it again is a bit harder to accomplish than a generic method...

Comment: Works with generic interfaces too. `f<TCollection, TElement>(TCollection collection) where TCollection : ICollection<TElement>, INotifyCollectionChanged`

Answer (score 1):

The first way you mentioned by creating a super interface appeals OO code because it allows one to express a class as the **combined** interfaces and interact with it as such.

Since there is a need for such expression, why not make it official and *tie the knot* by making it a super interface and having it *documented* for possible future maintenance. IMHO

Comment: Additionally, if you have multiple methods that need the combined interface, it's less verbose to declare the combined interface once than to restate the generic constraint multiple times.